# LocationMatch in the virtual host not working

Tags: apache-http-server

I need to disable the cache for certain urls.

I started useing these directives in the .htaccess file, and they work:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
```

These directives work for any urls of the website.
Since I need these directive work just for certain urls, I moved them to the virtual host file, useing `LocationMatch` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot ...
        ServerName ...

        <Directory ...>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <LocationMatch "/compile">
            Header unset ETag
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
            Header set Pragma "no-cache"
            Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

This code does not work anymore.

Comment: Is your Cache-Control header really truncated like that?

Comment: @grawity mmhm, yes, there was a typo when I copied that. Anyway I corrected and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to use `LocationMatch`? The way you use it, it applies whenever `/compile` is *anywhere* in the URL’s path. // Turn up the log verbosity to find out more.

Comment: @DanielB when I am sure it works I can specific more the regex, but I now I am trying. How can I turn up the log verbosity?